# Using LibreSSL 3.1.1 without messing with the system

Tags: macos, catalina, homebrew, ssl, openssl

I did a brew install of OpenSSL/LibreSSL (3.1.1)...

it's located in

`/usr/local/opt/libressl/bin/openssl`

I also have the usual macOS `Catalina` OpenSSL/LibreSSL bin at:

`/usr/bin/openssl`

I don't wanna mess with the system.

I know brew says it's `keg-only` and not symlinked into `/usr/local`.

This makes sense to not mess with system `openssl` calls.

Can I do my own alias to the `/usr/local/opt/libressl/bin/openssl` latest version with something like:

`alias libressl="/usr/local/opt/libressl/bin/openssl"` in my `.zshrc` so that I can use `libressl 3.1.1` for one off command line things without messing with my macOS system stability?

Comment: I don’t see why it would.  Apple includes older versions of utilities mostly for GPL license issues.  Newer versions of utilities installed via brew or macports won’t break anything.

Comment: @woodstock did this work for you?

Comment: Yep worked well.